# Version control ad hoc google bigquery scripts in github

Tags: github, google-bigquery

Is there any way to open sql scripts that are version controlled in GitHub in the BigQuery console?

Right now the only mechanism that I am aware of is to copy and past from the GitHub repo into the BigQuery console, but I'm hoping there is a more direct way to link the two. Unable to find any material saying this is or is not possible.

Comment: I don't know of a way to DIRECTLY open sql files into BigQuery, but there is a Google Cloud Platform API that you can use to read your sql files as the text to run the sql in BigQuery. I personally use Python.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3rd party IDE for BigQuery supporting GitHub - This is Goliath - part of [Potens.io](https://potensio.zendesk.com/) Suite available at [Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/potens-io/potensio).

[image]

***Note**: Another tool in this suite is Magnus - Workflow Automator. Supports all BigQuery, Cloud Storage and most of Google APIs as well as multiple simple utility type Tasks like BigQuery Task, Export to Storage Task, Loop Task and many many more along with advanced scheduling, triggering, etc. Supports GitHub as a source control as well*

***Disclosure**: I am GDE for Google Cloud and creator of those tools and leader on Potens team*